# MYSQL Calculate Conversion Rate

Tags: mysql, sql

I could manage to return the correct Conversion Rate with this query:

**SELECT
date(ordertime),
(count(*) / (
SELECT
sum(uniquevisits)
FROM
s_statistics_visitors
WHERE
datum = '2020-11-25') * 100) AS 'CONVERSION RATE'
FROM
s_order
WHERE
date(ordertime) = '2020-11-25'
AND subshopID = 1
GROUP BY
date(ordertime);**

But it only returns the CR for one specific date. It wont work with the between keyword.
The subquery returns more then one result, if I delete the where condition in the subquery.

Schema for s_statistics: id, shopID, datum, uniquevisits, devicetype
Schema for s_order: id, ordernumber, ordertime, shopID

Since s_statistics saves values for each devicetype I have to sum uniquevisits per day. But the group by date(ordertime) at the end of my query does not affect the subquery.

-original post-
I want to calculate the conversion rate for an onlineshop.

The data is held in two tables.

Schema1 statistics: `id / shopID / datum(yyyy-mm-dd) / uniquevisits / devicetype`

Schema2 order: `id / ordernumber / ordertime (YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS)`

Upon my knowledge the conversionrate calculates like:

```
(unique visits per day / 1000) * orders per day
```

**I tried something like this:**

```
SELECT
((count(ordernumber) / 1000) * (select sum(s_statistics_visitors.uniquevisits) 
FROM s_statistics_visitors GROUP BY* datum))

FROM s_order where subshopID= '1' 
GROUP BY date_format(ordertime, '%d%m%y') 
ORDER BY date_format(ordertime, '%d%m%y')
```

I know that my query wont work - since there is no join - but I believe it might be the right approach. I could you join on the the date.

The problem:
the dateformat in the table: `s_statistics_visitors is YYYY-MM-DD`

and in order:  `YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS`

Comment: Can you include the table definition for `s_statistics_visitors` ?

Comment: I just updated my original post - hope that clarifies it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want something like this:

```
SELECT sv.datum, sv.shopId, count(*) as num_orders,
       (count(*) / 1000) / sv.uniquevisits)
FROM s_order o JOIN
     s_statistics_visitors sv
     ON sv.datum = DATE(o.ordertime) AND
        sv.shopId = o.shopId
GROUP BY sv.datum, sv.shopId, sv.uniqevisits ;
```

Note:  This assumes that `shopId` is in both tables -- which makes sense for how you have described the problem.  If not, you can adjust the shop id logic.

Comment: Thanks for you advice. 
I tried but it didnt work. But I am pretty happy that the join on date worked with the date() keword.
Meaning I can join both tables on date an even on shopID.

But the calculation is not correct yet.

The Conversion Rate is totally off.

Comment: Here is the query: 

SELECT 
Date(ordertime), s_statistics_visitors.datum,
(count(ordernumber) / 1000) * (SELECT sum(s_statistics_visitors.uniquevisits) 
FROM s_statistics_visitors) AS 'CONVERSION RATE'

FROM s_order
JOIN s_statistics_visitors
ON DATE(s_order.ordertime) = s_statistics_visitors.datum
AND s_statistics_visitors.shopID = s_order.subshopID
where ordertime != 0
group by ordertime

Comment: In fact the conversionrate should be between 1-7 but the results are like 1384.9990 and 4154.9970.

Comment: @CJWD . . . The query in your comment is not the query in this answer.

Comment: Yes you are right - I tried with the query in the answer, but that threw an error.

Comment: I have to add that in the table s_statistics_visitors the uniquevisits are stored per device. That is why I used sum(s_statistics_visitors.uniquevisits)